# Functions by refrences in R

Tags: r

I am new to R 
Are there function references in R 
Something like function pointers in C 
What does UseMethod do

Example

I have function like this

```
sayHello <- function(message){
    print(message)
}
```

And I want call this function later by something like this

```
callMethod("sayHello","message")
```

Comment: See [?do.call](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/do.call.html).

Comment: Thanks,Is it possible call a method of an object using do.call?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think R has many ways to do this. The first that comes to my mind is to parse the text and identify whether "sayHello" is a function and then execute it. As it follows:

```
fun <- eval(parse(text="sayHello"))

if( class(fun) == "function" )
  fun(message)
```